# Pandas: Replace column if 0 if it is not the max

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What I want to do is replace a column value with "0" if, for a given row, that column is not maximal. And conversely, replace the column value with "1" if, for a given row, that column IS maximal.

My data looks like this:

```
data = {
    "A": [1, 2, 3],
    "B": [3, 5, 1],
    "Max": ["B", "B", "A"]
}

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(data_df)
```

```
   A  B Max
0  1  3   B
1  2  5   B
2  3  1   A
```

But I want it to look like

```
   A  B Max
0  0  1   B
1  0  1   B
2  1  0   A
```

Comment: By "is maximal", do you mean has the maximum value row-wise among columns not called "Max", or do you mean "is the column specified in Max"?  In your first row, you have A=1 and B=3, but "Max" is A.

Comment: Ah my bad, was a typo

Comment: The `Max` column might be entirely unecessary. `data_df.eq(data_df.max(1), axis=0).astype(int)`, especially if multiple columns can share the max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
for col in ['A','B']:
    data_df[col] = data_df['Max'].eq(col).astype(int)
```

Or, you could do:

```
data_df[['A', 'B']] = (pd.get_dummies(data_df['Max'])
                       .reindex(['A','B'], axis=1, fill_value=0)
                      )
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but your second answer only works if all values are present in `Max`, also you don't need a loop for your first method

Comment: Honestly now its worse IMO.  That is an incredibly convoluted way of just doing `np.array(['A', 'B']) == df['Max'].values[:, None]`, which will be much faster

Comment: I'm not sure how it is worse. And I did think of the exact numpy broadcast solution, but then I thought it might be too much. It is indeed a good solution though.